# DynamoDB share capacity over a table group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

In Azure Cosmos DB it is possible to allocate x amount of throughput over a database with n collections. Is it also possible to allocate x amount of capacity over a table group with n amount of tables in DynamoDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such concept of "database" or table group in DynamoDB.  Each table is independent and can be used by one or more applications.  IAM Policies allows you [to define fine grained access at table or item](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadWriteCapacityMode.html) level.

You can [provision the read and write capacity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadWriteCapacityMode.html) that will be required for your applications or choose the "on demand" capacity where DynamoDB instantly accommodates your workloads as they ramp up or down to any previously reached traffic level. If a workload’s traffic level hits a new peak, DynamoDB adapts rapidly to accommodate the workload.  On demand is the option to chose when you create new tables with unknown workloads or when you have unpredictable application traffic or when you prefer the ease of paying for only what you use.